# Codeigniter and Ckfinder csrf_exclude_uris

Tags: codeigniter, csrf, ckfinder

I'm having an issue with Codeigniter 3 and CKfinder regards the CSRF Protection

If I use the below in my Codeigniter Config file CKFinder image upload works fine

```
$config['csrf_protection'] = FALSE;
$config['csrf_token_name'] = 'csrf_test_name';
$config['csrf_cookie_name'] = 'csrf_cookie_name';
$config['csrf_expire'] = 7200;
$config['csrf_regenerate'] = TRUE;
$config['csrf_exclude_uris'] = array();
```

if I change the $config['csrf_protection'] = TRUE; CKFinder image uploads fail

What I need is to be able to exclude CKFinder from falling under the CSFR Protection - I've tried the below but nothing seems to work:

```
$config['csrf_exclude_uris'] = array('assets/plugins/ckfinder/.*+', 'assets/plugins/ckfinder/ckfinder.js', 'assets/plugins/ckfinder', 'admin/news/.*+');
```

Any pointers would be appreciated

Comment: you need to find a way to send csrf token along with all ajax and also update csrf token on html side after ajax response.

Comment: you should mention all URI which should not check for csrf. What URL it shows in network tab of browser debug console ? it will help you to decide proper URI.

Comment: The CKFinder $post varies depending on the action. One example is:  /assets/plugins/ckfinder/core/connector/php/connector.php?command=DeleteFiles&lang=en&type=Images&currentFolder=%2F&hash=91aa280181912a4c - I need to be able to exclude:  /assets/plugins/ckfinder/core/connector/php/* but I'm not sure how I do this?

Comment: try `$config['csrf_exclude_uris'] = ['assets/plugins/ckfinder/.*?'];`

Comment: thank you - but that didn't work

Comment: Hard luck.. I think you should debug the csrf token checking part of framework. You will get idea how you can do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
# Its work fine #
$config['csrf_protection'] = TRUE;
if(isset($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"])){
  $parts = explode("/",$_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);
  $exclude_url_arr = array('login');
  if (!empty($exclude_url_arr[0])) {
    foreach($parts as $part) {
      if (in_array($part,$exclude_url_arr)) {
          $config['csrf_protection'] = FALSE;
          break;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Hope this may work. it worked in my case.

```
$config['csrf_exclude_uris'] = array('assets/plugins/ckfinder/[\s\S]*');
```

but as far my knowledge "assets" resources don't need any csrf protection.

Answer (score 0):

URL which submit the form data.

Add lines below in `config.php` file. This will work.

```
$config['**csrf_exclude_uris**'] = array(
        *'device/deviceProcess/pushData'*
);

-- deviceProcess : Controller

--- pushData : Method

----- URL : http://hostname/index.php/device/deviceProcess/pushData
```